# $P(a<X<b,c<Y<d)\ge 1-P(X\geqslant b\ \text{ or } X\leqslant a)-P(Y\geqslant d\ \text{ or } Y\leqslant c)$

Tags: probability, inequality

I am sure I am missing a very silly point, due to which I am not being able to deduce that

> $$P(a<X<b,c<Y<d)\ge 1-P(X\geqslant b\ \text{ or } X\leqslant a)-P(Y\geqslant d\ \text{ or } Y\leqslant c)$$

$X,Y$ are continuous random variables, $\ Y>0$. Nothing is said about the dependence of $X$ and $Y$.

Can someone tell me what is the intermediate step I am missing?

Comment: Maybe it is $P(X \leq a \lor X \geq b)$ and $P(Y \leq c \lor Y \geq d)$?

Comment: @NP-hard What does $\lor$ mean?

Comment: $\lor$ means "or"

Comment: @NP-hard Fine. But I don't get your point

Comment: Note that $P(a < X < b \land c < Y < d) = 1 - P(X \leq a \lor X \geq b \lor Y \leq c \lor Y \geq d)$ and $P(X \leq a \lor X \geq b \lor Y \leq c \lor Y \geq d) \leq P(X \leq a \lor X \geq b) + P(Y \leq c \lor Y \geq d)$.

Comment: @NP-hard Aha ! I get it . Thanks.

Comment: The current RHS is $-1$. Not much to prove, then.

Comment: @Did can you please explain further?

Comment: Note that for every $a\leqslant b$ and $c\leqslant d$, $$P(X\geqslant a\ \text{ or } X\leqslant b)=P(Y\geqslant c\ \text{ or } Y\leqslant d)=1$$ and that $$1-1-1=\ldots$$

Comment: @Did How is $$P(X\geqslant a\ \text{ or }X\leqslant b)=P(Y\geqslant c\ \text{ or }Y\leqslant d)\ \ ?$$ They are not said to be equal in distribution!

Comment: Both probabilities are equal to $1$ (hence indeed they are equal but this is not he main point you should focus on).

Comment: @Did From what do you infer that the probabilities are equal?

Comment: @Did Please explain.

Comment: Wow. Because, if $a\leqslant b$ and $c\leqslant d$, then $$[X\geqslant a\ \text{or}\ X\leqslant b]=[Y\geqslant c\ \text{or}\ Y\leqslant d]=\Omega$$

Comment: @drhab OH GOD.. WHAT A TYPO.. I am extremely sorry..

Comment: @drhab IS it okay now?

Comment: Quote: "Maybe it is P(X≤a∨X≥b) and P(Y≤c∨Y≥d)? – NP-hard 3 hours ago"

Comment: @Did I am extremely sorry for my typos. Please forgive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

If $A,B\subseteq\mathbb R$ then:$$\mathbb R^2=(A\times B)\cup (A\times B^c)\cup (A^c\times B)\cup (A^c\times B^c)$$

and we are dealing with a union of disjoint sets.

If $\mu$ is a probability measure on $(\mathbb R^2,\mathcal B)$ and the sets are measurable then we find:$$1=\mu(\mathbb R^2)=\mu(A\times B)+\mu(A\times B^c)+\mu(A^c\times B)+\mu(A^c\times B^c)$$

What happens if you apply this on $A=(a,b)$ and $B=(c,d)$?

Comment: Nice. (But maybe denote the probability measure on $\mathbb R^2$ by $\mu$, not $\Pr$, since $\Pr$ is a measure on $\Omega$ and since this identity will be used for $\mu=\Pr_{(X,Y)}$.)

Comment: Can you please edit your answer, since I have corrected my typos?

Comment: Do you see that this implies $1\leq\mu(A\times B)+\mu(A^c\times\mathbb R)+\mu(\mathbb R\times B^c)$? And what if you apply that on $A=(a,b)$ and $B=(c,d)$?

Comment: @drhab Lovely . Thanks..